# RabbitMQ configured with `persistent: true` and `durable: false`

Tags: rabbitmq

From RabbitMQ [documents](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html) I see that if a queue created with `durable: true` and a message sent to this queue with `persistent: true` the message will be resent in case of RabbitMQ service crash before an ack sent for this message (in most cases, and if `noAck: false`).

What will happen if a message is sent with `persistent: true` but a queue was created with `durable: false`?

And is there any scenario that such configuration (`persistent: true` & `durable: false`) can make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And is there any scenario that such configuration (persistent: true & durable: false) can make sense?

Not really. In fact, support for non-exclusive, non-durable queues will be removed in RabbitMQ 4.0.

Comment: So in this case the `persistent: true` has no impact at all?

Comment: Yes, `persistent: true` means the messages are written to disk. But `durable: false` means that queues will not survive a server restart. As you pointed out, the combination really doesn't make sense.